# CakePHP 4: How to read session data in table class(Model)?

Tags: session, cakephp, model, cakephp-4.x

I have upgraded CakePHP from version 3.6 to 4.0, in version 3.6 i can access session in model using following workaround,

```
use Cake\Network\Session;
public function getSessionUser() {
    $session = new Session();
    return $session->read('Auth.User');
}
```

Now problem is that in newer version 4.0 , it is giving error **"Class 'Cake\Network\Session' not found"**.

Can anyone help how to access session in model in cakephp 4 version ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't do that! The model shouldn't know about the session and create a hard dependency, instead you should inject either the user data, or maybe the session object (retrieved from the request object) into the model. That can for example be achieved by using events, depending on where exactly you need to use the data, for example listen to `Model.beforeSave` and inject the user data into the options data.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. First, you need to use the below line in starting of class

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```

Then simply create an object of session like this

```
$session = Router::getRequest()->getSession();
```

and then you read the session in table class

```
$session->read("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 4.0, you need to use

```
Cake\Http\Session\CacheSession::read()
```

https://api.cakephp.org/4.1/class-Cake.Http.Session.CacheSession.html#read

Answer (score -1):

I have found solution is that change **use Cake\Network\Session** to **use Cake\Http\Session** in model.